# Print php table with Print function via Printer

Tags: php, mysql, printing

I have the following php table, how do i add print functionality just to the php table? And a button that when clicked, the following table is printed via printer, I tried 'CTRL+P' and I only got the html secton of the page example the header, footer, navigation bar, and not the results php results

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1' id= results>
<tr>
<th>FILEID</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Issue Date</th>
<th>Interest Rate</th>
<th>Terms</th>
<th>Balance Outstanding</th>
<th>Balance Outstanding</th>
<th>New Loan</th>
<th>Principal Repayment for $l_month</th>
<th>Principal Repaid</th>
<th>Balance Outstanding</th>
<th>Interest Payment for $l_month </th>
<th>INTEREST ACCUMULATED DURING FINNANCIAL YEAR</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {


  echo "<tr>"; 

    echo "<td>" . $row['app_file_id'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['app_fname']."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['app_lname']."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['commit_date'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['computer_interest'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['loan_life'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['avg(app_ln_amnt)'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['Balance Outstanding'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['New Loan'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['SUM(r.receipt_on_principal)'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['Principal Repaid'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['avg(app_amnt_owed)'] ."</td>";    
    echo"<td>". $row['SUM(r.receipt_on_interest)'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['Interest Accumilated'] ."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: What application are you using to print this? Do you mean you only want to print the code, or the processed html?

Comment: "only got the html secton of my document", what do you mean? Also, the table structure is invalid HTML.

Comment: its a section of a php code I am trying to print the results from the table but all i am gettin is the template of the page and no results, the template is the html section example, the navigation bar, header images footer etc

Comment: use css to hide other elements - @media print {
.noPrint {
    display:none;
}
}

Answer (score 4):

PHP doesn't send Events to a Browser. You can do that with Javascript.

`<input type="button" onclick="window.print()" value="Print Table" />`

To hide all the other Stuff you don't want to print add this to your html:

```
<style media="printer">
      .noprint * {
          display:none;
      }
```

And assign the css class noprint to the parent element you don't want to get printed.

Not tested but this could work too:

```
body {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.printthis {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

And give your table the class printthis and so only the table gets printed.

Comment: The php data is still not printing :(

Comment: Could you post your modified PHP script now? Guessing scripts is difficult, you know? :)

Comment: @PierreGeier: can you post the full script for this or a working html page? because I tried this and it didn't worked.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, take a look at my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hBCgA/ i noticed i had a typo in my script example it has to be "printer". You just need a class or a css selector that is only visible when the page gets printed. You can do this by changing the css media type. It is possible to use media queries but they are not very well supported http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

I am new to php, but the only way I know of doing them functions is through javascript.

Below is some code which will display a print button and send it to a printer, if using google chrome you will get a print preview screen come up first, with other browsers it will solely open up the small printing window.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
if (window.print) {
document.write('<form><input type=button name=print value="Print Page"onClick="window.print()"></form>');
}
</script>
```

With websites you have to be very careful with the formatting, http hates to print, so it is best to have minimal scripts on the page, otherwise half of the page will be spacing. especially if using things like drop down menus as in printing all of the < ul > and < li > statements convert to bullet points down the page. Otherwise I would probably recommend to look at displaying the page as pdf, where you would have much more control over the page layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1' id= results>
<tr>
<th>FILEID</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Issue Date</th>
<th>Interest Rate</th>
<th>Terms</th>
<th>Balance Outstanding</th>
<th>Balance Outstanding</th>
<th>New Loan</th>
<th>Principal Repayment for $l_month</th>
<th>Principal Repaid</th>
<th>Balance Outstanding</th>
<th>Interest Payment for $l_month </th>
<th>INTEREST ACCUMULATED DURING FINNANCIAL YEAR</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {


  echo "<tr>"; 

    echo "<td>" . $row['app_file_id'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['app_fname']."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['app_lname']."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['commit_date'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['computer_interest'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['loan_life'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['avg(app_ln_amnt)'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['Balance Outstanding'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['New Loan'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['SUM(r.receipt_on_principal)'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['Principal Repaid'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['avg(app_amnt_owed)'] ."</td>";    
    echo"<td>". $row['SUM(r.receipt_on_interest)'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['Interest Accumilated'] ."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
?>
<button onclick="javascript:window.print();"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this JavaScript at the end:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printpage()
  {
  window.print()
  }
</script>
<?php
echo "<table border='1' id= results>
<tr>
<th>FILEID</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Issue Date</th>
<th>Interest Rate</th>
<th>Terms</th>
<th>Balance Outstanding</th>
<th>Balance Outstanding</th>
<th>New Loan</th>
<th>Principal Repayment for $l_month</th>
<th>Principal Repaid</th>
<th>Balance Outstanding</th>
<th>Interest Payment for $l_month </th>
<th>INTEREST ACCUMULATED DURING FINNANCIAL YEAR</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {


  echo "<tr>"; 

    echo "<td>" . $row['app_file_id'] . "</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['app_fname']."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['app_lname']."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['commit_date'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['computer_interest'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['loan_life'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['avg(app_ln_amnt)'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['Balance Outstanding'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['New Loan'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['SUM(r.receipt_on_principal)'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['Principal Repaid'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['avg(app_amnt_owed)'] ."</td>";    
    echo"<td>". $row['SUM(r.receipt_on_interest)'] ."</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['Interest Accumilated'] ."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Print this page\" onclick=\"printpage()\" />";
?>
```

if you wish while user open this document the printer will turn on you can use the function in onload event in body:

```
<body onload="printpage()">
```

Good luck : )

Comment: Its still not printing the php content in the table :(